How to set RLS on Power BI dataset dependent on the report the dataset is used for?
I have a semantic model (also called a dataset) in Power BI which I have multiple Power BI reports connected to. One of the columns in the dataset is [employee_username] in the table [employees]. This table has a relationship with another table called [employee_work] which contains rows of work items. Now I have a report where I would like the employee that is logged in to only see the work related to them, for this I am applying RLS on [employee_username] in the dataset. However, for another report I want the employee that is logged in to see all work. How to handle RLS in the dataset dependent on the report?
I already tried:

adding a report table to the dataset

adding RLS on the employee table using the code below
VAR ReportX = SELECTEDVALUE(Report[Report_Name])
RETURN
IF(ReportX = "title report 1",
employee[employee_username] = USERPRINCIPALNAME(),
TRUE
)



RLS is set at the dataset and not the report, so what you are wanting isn't possible. Suggestion would be not to use RLS and instead use a Measure to filter based on USERPRINCIPALNAME() and in the other report to not use that measure.
